# SQL time clock data manipulation

Tags: sql

We have a SQL 2008 table that holds the attendance data in the following sequence.

```
 uid   clock                          collectdate                  type

 1    2012-10-30 16:13:07.000          2012-10-30 19:29:58.000     in
 1    2012-10-30 21:18:50.000          2012-10-30 22:29:58.000     in
 2    2012-10-30 16:13:07.000          2012-10-30 19:29:58.000     in
 2    2012-10-30 21:18:50.000          2012-10-30 22:29:58.000     in
```

The proper sequence will be to have the "Type" column as, in and out.  But this is exactly the problem I am facing as the system is being use to manage contractors and part timers who always miss pressing the correct button or not at all on the timeclock before making an in or out punch.

We currently depend on this stored procedure to put the timeclock data in the proper order

```
    INSERT INTO attendanceTBL (UID,CollectDate,Clockin,Clockout)

SELECT 
UID
,CollectDate
,MAX(case when type  = 'in' then clock end) clockin
,MAX(case when type  = 'Out' then clock end) clockout
From RAWCLOCKTBL
GROUP BY UID,CollectDate 
RETURN
```

Is there any way I can move the "clock" value to the same row in the correct sequence while ignoring the "type" column.  ie, move the above table to.

```
uid    clock                          clock            
1      2012-10-30 16:13:07.000        2012-10-30 21:18:50.000
2      2012-10-30 16:13:07.000        2012-10-30 21:18:50.000
```

Comment: It may just be me, sorry.  But, in what way is your desired output different from `SELECT uid, MIN(clock), MAX(clock) FROM attendanceTBL GROUP BY uid`?

Comment: That will give me result of the entire datetime span instate of daily min,max time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following query groups the IN and OUT times of a UID for each date and JOINs on the UID and DATE to get the desired output. The LEFT JOIN will ensure to return those entries without an OUT yet (if that is needed).

```
SELECT 
    A.UID, 
    CONVERT(DATE, clock) 'ClockDate', 
    min(clock) 'ClockIn', 
    max(clock) 'ClockOut'
FROM 
    attendanceTBL 
GROUP BY uid, CONVERT(DATE, clock)
```

Comment: Isn't this the same as `SELECT UID, CONVERT(DATE, clock) 'ClockDate', min(clock) 'ClockIn', max(clock) 'ClockOut' FROM attendanceTBL group by uid, CONVERT(DATE, clock)`?

Comment: This doesn't handle the case where there is no logout yet, @Dems.

Comment: It appears to return exactly the same results as yours.  If, for example, there is only one row for a given date, both `A` and `B` will return the same value.  At present this calculates the `MIN` and then calculates the `MAX` and joins them together; that's the only difference between `A` and `B`.  As the `GROUP BY` is the same, there are no `JOIN` or `WHERE` clauses, and only the `MIN/MAX` changes, calculating them separately doesn't seem to change anything...

Comment: Thanks guys for the solution!..  How can I expand the query by excluding a range of typeid? ie, The typeid contain values ranging from H01, H02,... to H24  and these values represent.  H01=Clockin, H02=clockout, H03=frontdoorIN and so forth.  How can I exclude only H01, and H02 only.